# How to implement a 'load more' functionality in react native with redux saga?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

How to Add loadmore in react native flatlist

get result from redux

SearchScreen

const listing= useSelector((state) => state.adData.data);

```
<FlatList
          showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}         
          data={listings}
          keyExtractor={keyExtractor}
          removeClippedSubviews={true}
          onEndReached={loadMore}
          onEndReachedThreshold={0.8}
          windowSize={15}
          getItemLayout={getItemLayout}
          renderItem={renderItem}
        />


const loadMore = async () => {
    setpageCurrent((page) => page + 1);
  };
```

I'm try data concat     return { ...state, data: [...state.concat(payload)], 'loading': false };

Not working correctly

Reducer

```
export default function productReducer(
  state = initState,
  { type, payload, error }
) {
  switch (type) {
    // Get list products
    case Actions.GET_ADS:
      return { ...state, loading: true };
    case Actions.GET_ADS_SUCCESS:
    return {...state, data : payload,'loading': false};
 default:
      return state;
  }
```

Saga

```
function* fetchListingsSaga({ page }) {
  try {
    const data = yield call(getListings, { page });
    yield put({ type: Actions.GET_ADS_SUCCESS, payload: data.data.response });
  } catch (e) {
    yield put({ type: Actions.GET_PRODUCT_ATTRIBUTE_ERROR, error: e });
  }
}
```